# Which lane should I approach in when using the HandyCross roundabout travelling from Maidenhead to Booker

Tags: uk, driving, roundabouts

I am planning a trip from Maidenhead to Booker and would like to canvas opinion on the best lane lane discipline to follow when traveling from Maidenhead using the A404 to Booker using the A4010.

The markings on the road surface are all warn away and so the roundabout is very hard to use.

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/M40,+High+Wycombe+HP11/@51.6123543,-0.769856,17.46z/data=!4m16!1m10!4m9!1m3!2m2!1d-0.7689736!2d51.6126961!1m3!2m2!1d-0.7689582!2d51.6126031!3e0!3m4!1s0x48768a0e79ce08b5:0x3536919cf8890f12!8m2!3d51.6122491!4d-0.7690129

There is a very [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81310/which-lane-to-enter-on-this-roundabout-uk) about a different roundabout which is why I thought it would be ok to post this question here. If that is not the case, please explain why.

Comment: Follow what the Highway Code says. And as always, drive defensively and ignore aggressive drivers around you.

Comment: From looking at the Google maps satellite and street views, it appears to have markings on the lanes like "M40 Oxford" and "A4010". If so, any reason not to follow them?

Comment: the satellite image is old and most of the markings are worn away. The reason I asked this question here was that there is a similar question about a roundabout in Milton Keynes. Please don't downvote if you aren't local. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81310/which-lane-to-enter-on-this-roundabout-uk

Comment: Wow! This is what is called 'too localized'. Quite a pity, Travel doesn't have that close reason. Ironically, it's about to be closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: Surely if the correct lane had changed since the google images were taken, they'd have been repainted and the paint would be readable? So if the paint's not readable, that's a sign it hasn't changed from what the photos show?

Comment: How on earth is this too broad? This is a very specific question that will have one and only one answer.

Comment: I've not used that roundabout before, but assuming the layout hasn't changed since Google Street View was taken, it seems to me that you should be in the left hand lane in the section where the road is two lanes wide, and then when it broadens out to four lanes just before the actual roundabout, be in the second lane from the left as indicated by the signs. You know you should be in the left hand lane initially because the Booker exit is indicated as being to the left on the diagram on the sign; and there's a sign specifically telling you to be in the second-from-left lane in the four lane bit

Comment: Now, if someone can reopen the question so I can post that as an answer (or at least tell me why on earth it has been classified as "too broad") that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: On the actual roundabout it looks like you should remain in the second-lane from the left (four lanes on the approach branch out into one immediate exit and another four lanes, so you should be in the second from the left of the four after the immediate exit). The left hand lane then becomes the M40 exit, and so you're then in the left hand lane for the next exit, which is yours.